# Android: How do I circumvent invalidation / redraw of not effected layers?

Tags: android

I have a relative layout with several ImageViews (with transparent areas) above each other. The problem is: if I invalidate one of those, all other's onDraw() methods are called too. Is this normal?
I don't want all Layers (Views) to redraw since this is a big performance issue- I only want the invalidated view to redraw..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this normal?

Yes.

> since this is a big performance issue

Use [Traceview](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) to identify where your performance bottleneck lies.

Or, possibly, really do use [layers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#layers).

Or, if you are creating a game or something, don't use the widget framework, but instead directly draw to the `Canvas` (or use OpenGL).

Comment: Sorry, just to make sure: you are saying that e.g. if I have an animated button in one layout/view, overlapping a graphic layout/view (drawn in onDraw()), and i press the button (it animates...), the whole underlying graphic has to be drawn again? sounds weird to me- why is it that EACH view has an invalidate method then? ...

Comment: @stoefln: "the whole underlying graphic has to be drawn again?" -- the scope of a redraw will be anything Android thinks may need to be redrawn, and Android tends to think things may need to be redrawn that you might not think so yourself.

Comment: "Use Traceview to identify where your performance bottleneck lies." -> the bottleneck is the drawing of paths. I can't make this faster, all I would need is a possibility to cache the view, cause it only has to be drawn once (let's say when the app starts).

"Or, possibly, really do use layers." -> This is not supported by android 2.1

"...instead directly draw to the Canvas" -> that's what I do. I draw to the canvas in onDraw() of the view, but as I said, this takes some processing, which I can't afford each time some component on another view is redrawn.

Comment: @stoefln: "In all versions of Android, views have had the ability to render into off-screen buffers, either by using a view's drawing cache, or by using Canvas.saveLayer()."

Comment: could you tell me how to use Canvas.saveLayer()? I read the documentation twice, but still have no clue how to make use of it.

Comment: @stoefln: I haven't used it myself. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121302/understanding-androids-canvas-savelayer -- AFAIK, drawing to your own bitmap seems to be more popular (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423327/android-view-ondraw-always-has-a-clean-canvas)

Comment: Thanks- the hint with drawing your own cache bitmap, worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using `invalidate()` on your `View`, perhaps you can try one of the [other](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28android.graphics.Rect%29) ones instead?  This would theoretically only redraw the affected (dirty) area.

```
void invalidate(Rect dirty)
void invalidate(int l, int t, int r, int b)
void invalidateDrawable(Drawable drawable)
```

See also [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wJYTBjMZJh0) video (around the 34:07 mark).  They have a nice little demo that describes this in detail.